# PTRACE_PEEKTEXT ptrace: Input/ouput error

Tags: c, debugging, virtual-memory, ptrace

I try to read the values from memory with using PTRACE_PEEKDATA.
To find the memory address of specific line I am using  with objdump - `objdump --dwarf=decodedline ./exe_filename`
and got the output:

```
test:     file format elf64-x86-64



Contents of the .debug_line section:



test.c:

File name                            Line number    Starting address    View    Stmt

test.c                                        23              0x1369               x

test.c                                        23              0x1385               x

test.c                                        28              0x1394               x

test.c                                        29              0x139d               x

test.c                                        30              0x13c5               x

test.c                                        35              0x13cf               x

test.c                                        36              0x13da               x

test.c                                        37              0x13e3               x

test.c                                        38              0x13f2               x

test.c                                        42              0x13fc               x

test.c                                        44              0x1405               x

test.c                                        44              0x1423               x

test.c                                        45              0x1429               x

test.c                                        46              0x1438               x

test.c                                        50              0x1442               x

test.c                                        50              0x144d               x

test.c                                        50              0x1458               x

test.c                                        51              0x1466               x

test.c                                        52              0x1475               x

test.c                                        57              0x147f               x

test.c                                        57              0x149b               x

test.c                                        58              0x14a0               x

test.c                                        59              0x14af               x

test.c                                        63              0x14b9               x

test.c                                        64              0x14df               x

test.c                                        73              0x14fa               x

test.c                                        73              0x1505               x

test.c                                        73              0x1508               x

test.c                                        73              0x1513               x

test.c                                        74              0x1528               x

test.c                                        75              0x1548               x

test.c                                        76              0x1556               x

test.c                                        77              0x1581               x

test.c                                        78              0x15a3               x

test.c                                        79              0x15ae               x

test.c                                        79              0x15b2               x

test.c                                        79              0x15bc               x

test.c                                        79              0x15db               x

test.c                                        80              0x15e2               x

test.c                                        81              0x15ec               x

test.c                                        82              0x15fb               x

test.c                                        84              0x1605               x

test.c                                        84              0x1609               x

test.c                                        87              0x1635               x

test.c                                        87              0x163e               x

test.c                                        88              0x1647               x

test.c                                        88              0x164e               x

test.c                                        88              0x1652               x

test.c                                        88              0x165c               x

test.c                                        91              0x167c               x

test.c                                        91              0x169f               x

test.c                                        92              0x16a6               x

test.c                                        97              0x16cb               x

test.c                                        97              0x16ec               x

test.c                                        98              0x16f2               x

test.c                                        99              0x1701               x

test.c                                       103              0x170b               x

test.c                                       104              0x171a               x

test.c                                       104              0x1723               x

test.c                                       105              0x1728               x

test.c                                       105              0x1731               x

test.c                                       108              0x1754               x

test.c                                       112              0x1763               x

test.c                                       113              0x1789               x

test.c                                       120              0x17a4               x

test.c                                       121              0x17c9               x

test.c                                       122              0x17d5               x

test.c                                       125              0x17fb               x

test.c                                       127              0x181c               x

test.c                                       128              0x182b               x

test.c                                       128              0x1834               x

test.c                                       129              0x1838               x

test.c                                       132              0x1849               x

test.c                                       137              0x1858               x
```

Now, I use:

```
unsigned long long int addr = 0x13cf;
unsigned long long int orig_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void *)addr, 0);
if (orig_data == -1) {
     perror("ptrace2");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and got the error:
`ptrace2: Input/output error`

I thought maybe objdump return the offset, so I searched the base address to use the formula:
`base address + offset = virtual address`

I used with Detect It Easy and found that base address is 0.
So, I don't know why it's now working.

I tried also to get the memory address from gdb debugger while run:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe038) at /home/vboxuser/Documents/CreateDebugger/test.c:35

35      child_pid = fork();

(gdb) disas main

Dump of assembler code for function main:

   0x0000555555555369 <+0>: endbr64 

   0x000055555555536d <+4>: push   %rbp

   0x000055555555536e <+5>: mov    %rsp,%rbp

   0x0000555555555371 <+8>: sub    $0x130,%rsp

   0x0000555555555378 <+15>:    mov    %edi,-0x124(%rbp)

   0x000055555555537e <+21>:    mov    %rsi,-0x130(%rbp)

   0x0000555555555385 <+28>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax

   0x000055555555538e <+37>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)

   0x0000555555555392 <+41>:    xor    %eax,%eax

   0x0000555555555394 <+43>:    cmpl   $0x3,-0x124(%rbp)

   0x000055555555539b <+50>:    je     0x5555555553cf <main+102>

   0x000055555555539d <+52>:    mov    -0x130(%rbp),%rax

   0x00005555555553a4 <+59>:    mov    (%rax),%rdx

   0x00005555555553a7 <+62>:    mov    0x2c72(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555558020 <stderr@GLIBC_2.2.5>

   0x00005555555553ae <+69>:    lea    0xc53(%rip),%rcx        # 0x555555556008

   0x00005555555553b5 <+76>:    mov    %rcx,%rsi

   0x00005555555553b8 <+79>:    mov    %rax,%rdi

   0x00005555555553bb <+82>:    mov    $0x0,%eax

   0x00005555555553c0 <+87>:    call   0x5555555551d0 <fprintf@plt>

   0x00005555555553c5 <+92>:    mov    $0x1,%eax

   0x00005555555553ca <+97>:    jmp    0x55555555583e <main+1237>

=> 0x00005555555553cf <+102>:   call   0x555555555270 <fork@plt>

   0x00005555555553d4 <+107>:   mov    %eax,-0x11c(%rbp)

   0x00005555555553da <+113>:   cmpl   $0xffffffff,-0x11c(%rbp)

   0x00005555555553e1 <+120>:   jne    0x5555555553fc <main+147>

   0x00005555555553e3 <+122>:   lea    0xc45(%rip),%rax        # 0x55555555602f

   0x00005555555553ea <+129>:   mov    %rax,%rdi

   0x00005555555553ed <+132>:   call   0x555555555230 <perror@plt>

   0x00005555555553f2 <+137>:   mov    $0x1,%eax

   0x00005555555553f7 <+142>:   jmp    0x55555555583e <main+1237>

   0x00005555555553fc <+147>:   cmpl   $0x0,-0x11c(%rbp)

   0x0000555555555403 <+154>:   jne    0x55555555547f <main+278>

   0x0000555555555405 <+156>:   mov    $0x0,%ecx

--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

Also the addresses 0x00005555555553cf  and 0x7fffffffe038 didn't work.

in PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, I need to put the virtual address of line from the source code? how to find him? can ASLR affect on the address memory or it's fixed?
Or maybe the problem is in `child_pid`?

Please help, I am stuck a lot of time on the problem.
Thanks for helps!

BTW, I using in virtual machine Ubuntu 22.04.